# So I figured out what makes a good question: what is likely to generate good answers. What is a good answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers

So I figured out what makes a good question: what is likely to generate good answers. What is a good answer? I'm sure this has come up before, but, what, basically, is a good answer, beyond one that refers to philosophical literature to back up its claims?

Comment: here's some ideas beyond what appears in the question 1. demonstration of expertise 2. an unusual approach 3. a normal conclusion.

Comment: am i wrong? i know you're not meaningfully obliged to add a comment, but i think my sincere interest in not fucking up the site should be obvious by now??

Answer (score 4):

I mean you're kind of right that good questions and good answers go together, but if you want to say that good questions are good because of their answers, then that's problematic. It doesn't give space to poor questions with answers better than they deserve (super lazy questions, very basic questions which could've been easily answered had the OP read a page or two in a book or Wikipedia, questions which were closed because they're entirely opinion based but which received a brilliant answer expressing one side of the debate). It would mean that all old unanswered questions are bad, rather than just obscure or difficult to find resources for answering.

Comment: no i'm saying bad questions are bad because of how they would be answered!

Comment: that does not mean that good questions are good because of their answers, only that good answers have something to do with good questions.

Comment: ok well whatever, i'll throw my hands up and give up. the voting processes are to me subjective and insane. and i'll just ask whatever i want, and hope that my not understanding the voting processes doesn't annoy anyone, nor get me banned! peace